# Benefits of IO specialization in multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

Let's say we have some multi-threaded program that uses the producer-consumer pattern. Each thread does the following:

1. Takes work from shared blocking queue
2. Makes network request
3. Response is saved to disk
4. Response is parsed and adds more work to blocking queue

With the following setup, we have each thread doing both network and disk IOs. Would there be a benefit of making the threads more specialized in such a way that each thread only does either a network IO **or** a disk IO?

Comment: It would let you independently tune the number of disk threads vs network threads, which seems like it could be useful.